# Split a large file based on n th occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: linux, file, awk, split

Split a file into chunks based on the Nth occurrence of "//" in linux. Also don't remove the "//" at the end of the chunk files.

Sample input file:

```
ABC
BCDV
//
EFGF
HIJ
KLMDF
//
NOP
sdsd
sd sdvsd
sdsdsd dwe
//
er re er
DFer er
//
DFGHDF
//
```

If splitting with 2nd "//" output would be

First file

```
ABC
BCDV
//
EFGF
HIJ
KLMDF
//
```

Second file

```
NOP
sdsd
sd sdvsd
sdsdsd dwe
//
er re er
DFer er
//
```

Third file

```
DFGHDF
//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a multi-character `RS` (requires gnu awk):

```
$ awk -v n=2 'BEGIN { RS=ORS="//\n" } { print > ("xxx" int((NR-1)/n)) }' file
```

output:

```
$ cat xxx0
ABC
BCDV
//
EFGF
HIJ
KLMDF
//

$ cat xxx1
NOP
sdsd
sd sdvsd
sdsdsd dwe
//
er re er
DFer er
//

$ cat xxx2
DFGHDF
//
```